# access exchange mailbox from pop3 client other than outlook

Tags: exchange-server, pop3

I want to access my Exchange Mailbox using a pop client like Thunderbird, everytime i log in, i get the error logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
I checked the pop settings on my ECP and they enabled, also I made sure that the Exchange pop service is up and running and the plaintextlogin is enabled.
Any help will be kindly appreciated

Comment: The idea is to develop an email poller on pop3 to listen the an exchange mailbox

Comment: EWS Implements streaming subscription which is a great feature to listen to mailbox in exchange. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue, Exchange does not support unsecured connection, to solve the issue you just need to set connection security to "SSL/TLS" and authentication method "Standard Password" even though you enabled PlainTextLogin
HTH